# Sharepoint Timer Service is suddenlty stop Sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, timer-service

I have a farm which was installed from scratch, and the timer service is started, however sometimes the timer service is stop.

When I try to start it again, it says LogOn Failure, but the problem is that WE dont reset the sp_farm accounts password at anytime which makes no sense.

The event log is empty, there is nothing in it. In the ULS Logs, I am not sure what to look because we dont know the exact date and time when it stops working.

Comment: try to run the Repair-SPManagedAccountDeployment powerShell command and it will sync the password across all services. once it completed successfully then try to restart the timer service to verify that you are not getting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verify the following Points:

- If you got `Error 1069: The service did not start due to a logon failure` Try to provide the credentials again then start the service.

[image]

- Open Central Administration > Security > Configure Managed Accounts > Click on Edit for the Farm account > Check `Change password now` > `Use exsisting password` and enter the current account password.

[image]

- Make sure that the service account you are using is not disabled and that password hasn't expired by checking `AD Users and Computers`.
- The account has administrator privileges and Logon as a service permission.

  - Go to Local Security Policy by Running `secpol.msc`
  - Under Local Policies,> User Rights Assignment double click `Log on as a service`
  - ensure that the account is added below Local Security Setting.

[image]

- the service account is a member of the Administrators group on the local computer .